# how to get only english alphabet and numeric in PrestoSQL

Tags: sql, regex, presto

How to get only english alphabet and numeric in PrestoSQL

```
column A
hello12
hi
สวัสดี
```

What is want is only

```
hello12
hi
```

very appreciate all help .

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . this should do what you want:

```
where not regexp_like(a, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
```